# Live countdown in MVVM project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model, countdown

I have a MVVM-style project (in WPF C#) where I have users add events or projects etc to a database. Each event/project they set up would have a due date (standard DD/MM/YYYY style).

In my MainViewModel, I have setup my entire ViewList and everything shows perfectly but I do not know how to have the TextBox I have created next to each project name in the view have a live countdown timer that does not use too much memory so my thinking is that this should be done at the Model level.

How can I have the model incorporate this live dynamic value if the due date is at a later date than today (so all of those that are expired do not countdown)? I would like it so that the countdown starts the second the data is called upon and not have any user action required each time they log on to the system.

Comment: I would consider creating a custom control with a simple textbox.  Then I would create a dependency property for the current date, target date, and time interval of refresh.  Using those values I would create a timer function to update the countdown value by the refresh interval.  Give this a try and then post back if you have trouble

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it.

First, I'd expose a collection on my View Model that contained instances of a Model that contained information about each due date.

Next, I'd create a custom UserControl that encapsulated the UI for an individual element.  Might have the name, maybe some other info, and also that countdown timer.  It would also expose a public property for the due date.  This UserControl would be used in the ItemTemplate of the ViewList.  The due date property of the UserControl would be bound to the due date property of the Model.

Finally, in the codebehind of the UserControl (yes, MVVM != no codebehind!), I'd set a DispatcherTimer to fire every second that would subtract the current time from the due date and then update the UI.

You can add any other UI related logic (e.g., don't update after due, change from a countdown to static text "YOU'RE LATE", etc) in the UserControl.

I doubt there would be any issues with memory with this design.